# Boost Log thread-safe is not working

Tags: c++, logging, boost, thread-safety

I'm trying to make Log Macro with Boost and my macro is non thread-safe. Here is my sample code:

Initialization

```
inline boost::shared_ptr<cilog_async_sink_t> init_async_logger(const std::string& app_name,
  const std::string& target = "./log", int64_t rotation_size = 1024 * 1024 * 1024,
  bool auto_flush = true) {
  namespace expr = boost::log::expressions;
  namespace attrs = boost::log::attributes;
  namespace keywords = boost::log::keywords;
  boost::log::add_common_attributes();
  boost::shared_ptr<cilog_backend> backend(
    new cilog_backend(boost::filesystem::path(target), app_name, rotation_size, auto_flush));

  boost::shared_ptr<cilog_async_sink_t> sink(new cilog_async_sink_t(backend));
  sink->set_formatter(
    expr::stream << expr::format_date_time<boost::posix_time::ptime>("TimeStamp", "[%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S.%f] ")
      << "[" << expr::attr<severity_level, severity_tag>("Severity") << "] "
      << "[" << expr::attr<attrs::current_process_id::value_type>("ProcessID") << "] "
      << "[" << expr::attr<attrs::current_thread_id::value_type>("ThreadID") << "] "
      << expr::smessage);
  boost::log::core::get()->add_sink(sink);
  cilog_async_sink_t::locked_backend_ptr p = sink->locked_backend();
  return sink;
}
```

Format

```
class cilog_backend: public boost::log::sinks::basic_formatted_sink_backend<char,
    boost::log::sinks::synchronized_feeding> {
private:
    bool auto_flush_;
    boost::filesystem::ofstream file_;
    boost::filesystem::path target_path_;
    boost::filesystem::path file_path_;
    std::string file_name_suffix_;
    uintmax_t rotation_size_;
    uintmax_t characters_written_;
    boost::gregorian::date current_date_;

public:
  explicit cilog_backend(boost::filesystem::path const& target_path,
      std::string const& file_name_suffix, uintmax_t rotation_size,
      bool auto_flush) :
      auto_flush_(auto_flush), target_path_(target_path), file_name_suffix_(file_name_suffix),
      rotation_size_(rotation_size), characters_written_(0),
      current_date_(boost::gregorian::day_clock::local_day()) {
  }

  void consume(boost::log::record_view const& /*rec*/,
    string_type const& formatted_message) {
    if (current_date_ != boost::gregorian::day_clock::local_day())
      rotate_file();

    if (!file_.is_open()) {
      file_path_ = generate_filepath();
      boost::filesystem::create_directories(file_path_.parent_path());
      file_.open(file_path_, std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);
      if (!file_.is_open()) return; // failed to open file

      characters_written_ = static_cast<std::streamoff>(file_.tellp());
    }

    file_.write(formatted_message.data(), static_cast<std::streamsize>(formatted_message.size()));
    file_.put('\n');
    characters_written_ += formatted_message.size() + 1;

    if (auto_flush_)
      file_.flush();

    if ((file_.is_open() && (characters_written_ >= rotation_size_)) || (!file_.good()))
      rotate_file();
  }
};
```

I found some code for thread-safe on Boost:

```
 cilog_async_sink_t::locked_backend_ptr p = sink->locked_backend();
```

in my init but not working.

Can anyone advice for me?